# js.executeScript fails with Unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

https://www.companyfolders.com/proofs

I'm running a script in the browser's console on the above page:

```
let img = document.querySelector('.subscribe'),
style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

then typing 'bi' in console and pressing enter.
The result would be my expected URL:
"https://www.companyfolders.com/images/skin/bgr_header.png"

but when I'm trying to do this in Java: I'm navigating to this page then trying to execute:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String a = String.valueOf(js.executeScript("return let img = document.querySelector('.subscribe'), style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false), bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/\"/g, \"\");"));
System.out.println(a)
```

I see org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected identifier

if I'm trying to put 'return' statement before 'bi' var then I see error about return statement in JS.

Could you please explain how to implement this script, run and return the result of execution (String url) from Java Selenium ?

Comment: `return let img =` is not valid javascript

Comment: got it. But if I'll not use return statement I will save 'null' to my String a.
how can I fix this?

Comment: doe sit need to be a single statement? if not, ``let img = document.querySelector('.subscribe'), style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false), bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/\"/g, \"\");"); return bi``

Comment: if it can only be a single statement ...``return (document.querySelector('.subscribe').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.subscribe'), false)).backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/\"/g, \"\");")``

Answer (score 1):

if it can only be a single statement ...

```
return (document.querySelector('.subscribe').currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.subscribe'), false)).backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/\"/g, \"\");")
```

this works fine! Thanks Jaromanda X